# Graph data structures and journal format for mini-IDE

Tags: data-structures

Background:

I am writing a small/partial [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Code is internally converted/parsed into a graph data structure (for fast navigation, syntax-check etc). Functionality to undo/redo (also between sessions) and restoring from crash is implemented by writing to and reading from journal. The journal records modifications to the graph (not to the source).

Question:

I am hoping for advice on a  decision on data-structures and journal format.

For the graph I see two possible versions:
 *g-a* Graph edges are implemented in the way that one node stores references to other nodes via memory address
 *g-b* Every node has an ID. There is an ID-to-memory-address map. Graph uses IDs (instead of addresses) to connect nodes. Moving along an edge from one node to another each time requires lookup in ID-to-address map.

And also for the journal:
 *j-a* There is a current node (like current working directory in a shell + file-system setting). The journal contains entries like "create new node and connect to current", "connect first child of current node" (relative IDs)
 *j-b* Journal uses absolute IDs, e.g. "delete edge 7 -> 5", "delete node 5"

I could e.g. combine *g-a* with *j-a* or combine *g-b* with *j-b*. In principle also g-b and j-a should be possible.

[My first/original attempt was *g-a* and a version of *j-b* that uses addresses, but that turned out to cause severe restrictions: nodes cannot change their addresses (or journal would have to keep track of it), and using journal between two sessions is a mess (or even impossible)]

I wonder if variant *a* or variant *b* or a combination would be a good idea, what advantages and disadvantages they would have and especially if some variant might be causing troubles later.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 common data structures to represent graph(s): Adjacency Lists and Adjacency Matrices. They are listed [here](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) with their time/space complexities. Choose the one that's most appropriate based on the (estimated) complexity/density of your graph and the operations you expect to do on it most.

In my experience, I've always preferred a directed adjacency matrix (2D array of bool or float storing the existence or weight of the edge).

- It's dead simple to write/reason about.
- I've never had the need to add/remove vertices after initial construction time.
- The most common operation for my graphs is almost always querying, and that is O(1).
- I haven't had graphs large enough to worry about space.

That said, they have the same interface, so they're swappable.

Comment: Thanks for the nice link.  I wonder though how they compute the complexity for removing from the adjacency list to depend of the size of the graph.  In my code removal cost depends only on the degree of the vertex to be removed.

Comment: @matec: Removing a node requires going through all of the existing nodes (O(|V|)) and then removing all edges that go to the node you're removing (O(|E|)).